# Determine if exists a subgroup of order $3$ of $H=\langle\sigma^{8440}\rangle$

Tags: group-theory, discrete-mathematics, cyclic-groups, permutation-cycles

Consider the following permutation of $S_{13}$.

$\sigma=(1\;3\;13\;5\;11\;8)(2\;10\;4\;6\;12\;7\;9)$

Determine if exists a subgroup of order 3 of $H=\langle\sigma^{8440}\rangle$. If yes, exhibit it if no say why.

My attempt by using some properties of cyclic groups.

First of all, I calculated the order of $\sigma$ which is $ \operatorname{lcm}(6,7)=42$. Then the order of $\sigma^{8440}$ which is $\frac{42}{\gcd(8440,42)}$. Since $\gcd(8440,42) = 2$ then $|H|=o(\sigma^{8440}) = 21$ (since we are working with cyclic groups). 
Finally, since $3\mid21$, there exists a subgroup of $H$ of order $3$. I call it $G$ and it is generated by $\langle\sigma^{\frac{21}{3}}\rangle=\langle\sigma^{7}\rangle$.

Is my attempt correct?

Comment: Please don't use the comparison operators $<$ and $>$ as brackets, as the spacing is wrong. LaTeX provides `\langle` and `\rangle` ($\langle$ and $\rangle$).

Comment: @Christoph fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You make a mistake at the very end of your argument; $\sigma^7$ is *not* an element of $H$. Because $8440\equiv40\pmod{42}$ you have
$$H=\langle\sigma^{8440}\rangle=\langle\sigma^{40}\rangle=\langle\sigma^{-2}\rangle=\langle\sigma^2\rangle.$$
The subgroup $H\subset\langle\sigma\rangle$ is the subgroup of *even* powers of $\sigma$. I'll leave it to you (for now) to determine the subgroup of order $3$.

Besides this, you are entirely correct. Depending on how complete you want to be, you could

- note that $\sigma$ is given as a product of *disjoint* cycles, and *hence* its order is $\operatorname{lcm}(6,7)$.
- make explicit what the elements of the subgroup of order $3$ are, i.e. write out the appropriate powers of $\sigma$ in cycle notation.

Comment: $\langle\sigma^{40}\rangle=\langle\sigma^{-2}\rangle$

Comment: @egreg I agree, and I skipped right ahead to $\langle\sigma^{-2}\rangle=\langle\sigma^2\rangle$. Or are you suggesting this intermediate step would improve the answer? Hard to tell without words ;)

Comment: @Servaes I don't think I completely understand what you're saying. I eventually want to find a subgroup of H, if exist, of order 3. For the last part, I think it is sufficient to write its generator and not all the elements of it. So, at this point, I have no idea how to proceed since I believed that the property used in the last part (by using the order of H and its divisors) could be a good way to verify if such subgroup exists or not.

Comment: You are entirely correct in saying that $|H|=o(\sigma^{8440}) = 21$,  and that since $3\mid21$ there exists a subgroup of $H$ of order $3$. The point is that $H$ is *not* generated by $\sigma^{21}$ but by $\sigma^{\frac{42}{21}}=\sigma^2$, and that the subgroup of order $3$ is *not* generated by $\sigma^{\frac{21}{3}}$ but by $(\sigma^2)^{\frac{21}{3}}$.

Comment: @Servaes Considering the level, I'd add the intermediate step.

Comment: In fact, it is easy to check that $\sigma^{21}$ has order $2$, because $(\sigma^{21})^2=\sigma^{42}=e$, and similarly that $\sigma^2$ has order $21$. In the same way you can check the orders of all elements I listed in the comment above.